# Searching question with only tags provided?

Tags: feature-request, search, tag-search

Sometimes we need to search a question with one or more than one particular tags. With only those tags. Like if I want to search question on `java` then there should be a functionality to search question only with `java` tag not any other tag.

Comment: like... [tag:java] ? or do you mean *only* the java tag?

Comment: @MarcGravell Yes. With only `java` tag.